# How to get Mac Mail to show different Gmail addresses in the reply to field?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, gmail

I have a primary gmail account: me@gmail
My employer set up email that forwards to gmail as a different identity: me@mtk.org

Me@gmail downloads to my Mail inbox on Mac. I can reply to messages sent to thus account from my Mac.

Mail sent to @mtk.org Also downloads to the mail inbox on the Mac   BUT I CANNOT reply to these messages from the mtk email - it does not show up as an option in to select in the From drop down menu in Mail.  It would not be appropriate for me to reply to these messages from my personal Gmail address. Work email needs to be responded to from the work address

How do I get the MTK email address to show up in the drop-down menu on the Mac so that I can reply using that address?

Comment: So the @mtk.org is not set up a send in your Mac Mail. Go to Mail -> Preferences -> Accounts -> Outgoing Server ! what does it say there?

Answer (score 1):

I use Gmail for Work along with Mac Mail and how I got around this was by opening:

1. Preferences > Accounts
2. Then in the Email Address field I put a comma after the address that was there and then added the other address I wanted to be able to reply from. For me I added 4 different ones just by separating with a space and comma like this:

me@gmail.com, me@mtk.org, sales@mtk.org

Now, when I compose an email, there is a a drop down menu that allows me to choose which address I want to send my message from. The only caveat here, is that all of my addresses end in the same business name and it sounds like yours don't. I don't know how your boss has gmail for work set up, but this is easy to change and worth a try! If it doesn't work you can just go back to how the account was setup before, no harm, no foul.

Answer (score 0):

Was the me@mtk.org account added separately to Mail or the Mac? If not, you'll need to disable forwarding of the me@mtk.org account to the me@gmail account and add the me@mtk.org account to Mail or the Mac.

Comment: It was set up in gmail as an "additional email you own" under the Settings and Accounts tab. It is not set up as an alias in that location.

Comment: Another post stated I could add the email address somewhere in the mail settings for Google on the Mac under Mail Preferences. But I did not fund the instructions s to be clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to reply with a specific FROM email address, you need to set up this email account in Apple Mail.

When the new email account has been set up, you'll under the new email account's 'Outgoing Mail Server (SMTP)' setting have the server to use when replying - and by having this new account, you'll be able to choose it from the drop-down as the reply FROM address.

**EDIT:**

When you have set up the new mail account for @mtk.org, you'll have set up (configured) the Outgoing Mail Server too - and this Mail Server could be using your current GMail Server identity setup, which will work the same as 'kristcarmen' suggested in his answer, or it could be the correct Outgoing Mail Server used with @mtk.org, if the last, then all @mtk.org mails will be replyed 'the correct way'.

Needed server identity for your @mtk.org Mail Server: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203995 - if you look at your current GMail account set up, you can see what you need - so you need to get the same kind of server identity informations for setting up your @mtk.org account.

***Incoming mail server settings:***

- Account Type: Choose IMAP*, POP, Exchange IMAP, or Exchange EWS1, as directed by your email provider. If you're using a Microsoft Exchange account, see the Exchange setup instructions for [Mac](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT201951) or [iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT201729).
- Incoming Mail Server (host name): The host name of the incoming mail server, such as mail.example.com.
- User Name: Your user name for this account, such as appleseed. Some email providers want your full email address as your user name.
- Password: The email password you use to sign in to your account.
- Port: The port number used by the incoming mail server. [Common port numbers](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT202944) for incoming mail are 143 and 993 for IMAP accounts, and 110 and 995 for POP accounts.
- Authentication: Choose Password, MD5, NTLM, Kerberos, or None, as directed by your email provider.
- Use SSL? Does the incoming mail server support SSL (Secure Sockets Layer) or TLS (Transport Layer Security) encryption?

***Outgoing mail server (SMTP) settings:***

- Outgoing mail server (SMTP): The host name of the outgoing SMTP (Simple Mail Transfer Protocol) server, such as smtp.example.com.
- Port: The port number used by the outgoing mail server. Common port numbers for outgoing mail are 25, 465, and 587.
- Authentication: Choose Password, MD5, NTLM, Kerberos, or None, as directed by your email provider. If None, you may need the additional settings below to send email when you're on a different network, such as from a Wi-Fi hotspot or Internet cafe.
- Use SSL? Does the outgoing mail server support SSL or TLS encryption?

Comment: The last comment from you has typos and I'm not sure what " when set up you'll under the email account ". Means 

Comment: What info for server identity does my supervisor need to give me to add the account to apple/Mac mail?

Comment: Edited my answer with more details

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple Email Addresses for a single account in Mac Mail.
Once you do this, all of these addresses will be available in the "From" field of new mails.

To add new addresses, go to the preferences in Mac Mail and select your gmail account under "Accounts". In the "Account Information" tab you will find an "Email Address" pop up menu where you can choose "Edit Email Addresses…" to add/remove addresses to the given account.

However, **gmail might prevent you from sending mails from an email address that is not part of your account**. It might still accept your mail but then change the "From" address before delivering it. So, better check whether this works before sending important mails...